# python limit itertools result

Tags: python

I'm using `itertools` to get all combinations of a list:

```
import itertools

stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
    print(subset)
```

Is there a way to limit the result to e.g. combinations with at least 2 and at most 5 elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Permutations and combinations are two different things.

Comment: ok. ... i'll edit the post @chepner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the `for` loop.

```
import itertools

stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for L in range(2, 6):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
    print(subset)
```

Answer (score 8):

Limit the range to `[2, 6)`:

```
for L in range(2, 6):
   for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
      print(subset)
```